# ¿Hay alguna forma estándar para mostrar consultas de PL/SQL?

Tags: discusión, formato

Así como las etiquetas *HTML* llevan un nivel jerárquico y el código se puede ver de una forma comprensible, *¿Hay una forma estándar para escribir el código en las consultas **SQL**, en especial **PL/SQL**?*

Cuando realizo una pregunta o leo una pregunta hecha por otro desarrollador, la mayoría de las consultas tienen un formato diferente en la escritura.

Por ejemplo, veo tanto el caso 1:

```sql
SELECT CAMPO1 AS NOMBRE, CAMPO2 AS APELLIDO FROM TABLA
WHERE CONDICION;
```

Como el caso 2:

```sql
SELECT 
CAMPO1 AS NOMBRE,
CAMPO2 AS APELLIDO
FROM TABLA
WHERE CONDICION;
```

Comment: No termino de entender si esta es una pregunta para meta o el sitio principal. Te estas refiriendo a las preguntas del sito? o a algo en general de la vida? de cualquier forma, la pregunta no valdria tampoco para el sitio principal porque es basada en opiniones.

Comment: Me refiero a las preguntas echas en stack overflow

Comment: Claro.. sobre el sitio principal, por eso mi duda de a que apuntas con esta pregunta.

Comment: Meta es el subdominio en el que se discuten errores, opiniones y temas de gestión, con base en eso, no quise incurrir en errores al dar una opinión acerca que debiera existir un standar en la forma en que se escribe el código en stack overflow y por ello pregunte si ya lo hay y donde lo podría encontrar, si te pones a ver cada desarrollador tiene una estructura diferente para escribir el codigo sql, unos escriben primero el select abajo los campos otros el select y los campos en una linea y abajo el from y en plsql es mucho mas variable

Comment: Si te sirvió alguna respuesta puedes marcarla como correcta.

Comment: En realidad no creo que esté basada en opiniones, solo hay que buscar a ver si existe un estándar sobre eso, y si no existe responder que no, y si existe poner los enlaces a dicho estándar. Esta pregunta tendría que estar migrada al sitio principal.

Answer (score 3):

El sitio no tiene reglas al respecto.

Por lo tanto, podés escribir la query como más te guste. Cualquiera de los formatos es válido, dado que no hay una práctica común en cómo escribir un SQL.

Los dos formatos son correctos.

Lo unico que yo criticaría, es que le estas gritando al SQL... Todas las instrucciones en mayúscula, por lo menos a mí no me gustan (hace 3 años sí, ahora no).

```sql
SELECT CAMPO1 AS NOMBRE, CAMPO2 AS APELLIDO FROM TABLA
WHERE CONDICION;
```

Lo que sí, trata de usar el indentado para formatear el código:

```sql
select
    CAMPO1 AS NOMBRE,
    CAMPO2 AS APELLIDO
from
    TABLA
where 
    CONDICION;
```

Nota: A mí me gusta mucho más esta versión.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, debería existir un standar si toda la comunidad trabajara bajo un standar esto haría las preguntas que tienen querys mas efectivas y fácil de solucionar.

Comment: @JancelPerez cuesta que escriban bien una Pregunta con un Ejemplo Minimo Verificable, si agregamos eso nos pondriamos muy exquisito y los usuarios nuevos se cansarian de que lo corrijan o le cierren preguntas

Comment: si a ver vamos, la identacion incluso en SQL puede cambiar, los  amantes a MySQL les gusta verlo [de una forma especial](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/08183/7)

Comment: No creo que se deba exigir ningún estándar para escribir cualquier código en SQL ni en cualquier otro lenguaje (salvo python), lo que sí, no esta de más pedir mayor legibilidad al mismo, un forma es solicitarle amablemente al AP que mejore la escritura, y otra forma más proactiva es editarlo directamente con cuidado de no romper nada. En el caso de SQL muchas veces, escriben el código completo en una única línea, suelo en esos casos editar el código original con un estándar similar al de @gbianchi, aunque en mi caso, muchas veces termina gritándole al motor.